# Typescript - Implementing Either with a tuple for error handling

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to compose a type which represents a tuple that returns either an error or the value?

```
async function createUser(userData): Promise<Either<User, UserError>> {}

// This should return a tuple where we have either an user or an error. Not both, not none
const [ user, userError ] = await createUser({ ... })

// Checking if there is an error
if (userError) {
    ...
    // This line represents an early bail, could be throw or return
    throw userError
}

// Since we check the error above, this should now be safe to use
console.log(user.name)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such a type like this:

```ts
type Either<A, B> = [A, undefined?] | [undefined, B];
```

And it will be handled by TypeScript's control flow analysis the way you want it to:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqSBTATs0sD2oAukBDXCAZVAGMsA7WaAEzXn0QNAFss6BXAGwwDMsqCABkAgqAAOXVJKyxksAFDIAHnNTEA3gF8A3EqW4AnpIwBRaPjQAeMQBpQAIQB8oALygA2g9BcqDPzQVMh0APwAuqAAPt7+gcGhjk4RBkamGACqCsKeWqBUBGzIAFyYuKjBAOag+obkPASw8Nlo5qioQqBquMgB8O2dwlpKoKBYAG5olQwFRRieAOStqINCiwY6hgwNBOig-P7kuNDUFOhEyCsAFFw5ACJEBGUrAJRlAAqdbHDINpbWVA2FaOFZrVAuFxpSg0YhePw5Rx3NodLpRTwEADuBCs52QlxuWkKxTKi0EWEWOleaWRqD0oBAoBWMT8AWQQRCdCUtPB9MZYNRwli8XZiS5Smg-FAtxy4NeoBGYx5gr5YAFQ1GeEgnUxCJRQ02hlpqqZOW5OQAdMTkCbYBVqkogA)

```ts
type Either<A, B> = [A, undefined?] | [undefined, B];

type User = { name: string };

class UserError extends Error {
  override name = 'UserError';
}

declare function createUser(userData: User): Promise<Either<User, UserError>>;

const [ user, userError ] = await createUser({name: 'foo'});

user; // User | undefined
userError; // UserError | undefined

if (userError) {
  userError; // UserError
  throw userError;
}

user; // User
user.name; // string
```

---

However, I prefer using a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to avoid the extra tuple and variable (inspired by [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)'s [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) type):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=4&ssc=1&pln=30&pc=1#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdTqSBTATs0sD2oAukBDXCAZVAGMsA7WaAEzXn0QNAFss6BXAGwwDMsqCABkAgqAAOXVJKyxksAFDIAHnNTEA3gF8A3EqW4AnpIwAlRb2IAecKAC8oAG5Z6AGlABRUGtzIqOngvVFQhR29QoQA+CPsAH28DJX4uKnJcaGoEWBCw4TtogApnAh4uZAAuCABKatLyjER7ADJI-NAtJVBQdFwZKhcyioQaXAJ05Cx+dqEDHUMTM1AAVQVhJy1QKgI2KsxcVGgqAHNQfUNyHgJYeDW0PPC-AKDZ4S6erGc0I4Zt3YwTgA5PdUI9UED5oYGFcCOhQKl0plsuR0ERkKCilx1gARIgEaqguqgAAKYTYcGQNkssGsNlBnlB4Oi0WSlDGoGxaAiBAA7gRoMRUch0ZitDs9tUgYIsECdDVklzUHpQCBVutQIkmVFUIZoDMinBwVj1jUap1upz1iq1dr8pa1QA6Z2gOg4bB7ZinXw8BSW-BhXlWtBQpRKm1gUFh9aOiXICMHI6nJRAA)

```ts
type Result <T = void, E extends Error = Error> = T | E;

function isError <T>(value: T): value is T & Error {
  return value instanceof Error;
}

type User = { name: string };

class UserError extends Error {
  override name = 'UserError';
}

declare function createUser(userData: User): Promise<Result<User, UserError>>;

const user = await createUser({name: 'foo'});

user; // User | UserError

if (isError(user)) {
  user; // UserError
  // ... do something else
  throw user;
}

user; // User
user.name; // string
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly, if you don't check the error, `user.name` could result in a type error, but Typescript doesn't catch it. I saw a couple of examples with similar types or Result classes with .ok and .fail methods, but that seemed more complex than a tuple and this is why I wondered if it could be a accomplished that way, but maybe it can't

Comment: @DiyanSlavov this is because both `Error` and `User` have `name` property. Please keep in mind, this is just a type wrapper, don't treat this approach as a full monadic. If you want to go into FP, consider using [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts)

Comment: I'm referring to the first example that was an answer to my question, not his second proposition. The solution that he proposed does not work properly for me. I'm not looking to go full on anything in FP, I just wanted this simple thing so that I can improve the error handling in my app

Comment: @DiyanSlavov “_could result in a type error, but Typescript doesn't catch it_”: What do you mean? Can you show an example in a playground link? As you can see in the playground link above, TS does infer according to your criteria.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake on my part with the error, I must have messed something up. But here's a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-rw7m47?file=/src/index.ts where I explicitly check the error, if so - early bail. So, user is impossible to be undefined, but the compiler tells me that it can be. The desired outcome for me is to have one or the other. If I have an error, then user is null, and if I have an user, the error is null

Comment: @DiyanSlavov The reason why you are experiencing issues in CodeSandbox is because it currently uses an older version of TypeScript (v 4.5.5) before support for [Control Flow Analysis for Destructured Discriminated Unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) was added in version 4.6 (and gives you no way to use a newer version).

Comment: @DiyanSlavov If you're using an IDE with an older version of TS, you'll have to assign the result to a single tuple variable, then discriminate it by its numeric indexes. (And in that case, my second suggestion will probably be more ergonomic.)

Comment: My VSCode uses TS 4.6.4, but I cannot get this thing to work. I copy-paste the code into the typescript playground and it works properly with the early bails, but in my editor it does not work. Do you happen to have an idea on why that might be

Comment: More information is needed (e.g. what is your TSConfig?), and that’s actually a separate question. You are welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I would post another question but I don't know how to describe the question, how is this feature called?